# Hardhat compile code on file change (like remix)

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat, compilation, compiler

Is there any way (preferably an official Hardhat plugin) to automatically compile the Smart Contracts' code on file change?

I'd want to have the same developer experience as when using Remix, or nodemon (in NodeJS).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's needed. Because every time we run any command in hardhat like `run`, `test` etc. the hardhat automatically matches the contract files with the already compiled artifacts, if there is a change in the contract then it compiles the new contracts. So there's no chance that we are deploying or testing old contracts even after changing the code.